# Operation Enduring Freedom, early results

Tags: afghanistan

i'm writing a text about Afghanistan from 1992-2001. And i want to finish of with how "Operation Enduring Freedom" resulted in great losses for the Taliban in a short period of time, but i'm having trouble finding good and direct sources. If anyone could help out, that would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please take a look at [How to Ask](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to gain insight into how to ask a question. This question will be much improved if [you show the results of your initial research](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/how-to-ask-a-question-at-se-history-is-there-a-template).

Comment: Before you ask this question, I suggest that you do some initial research.  [Here is an official source, downloadable in .pdf format](http://www.history.army.mil/html/books/070/70-122-1/CMH_Pub_70-122-1.pdf) that should provide some of the basics.

Comment: I would read and write about Ahmed Shah Massoud ("The Lion of Panjshir") and leave it at that.

Comment: @user14394 Didn't he die (got assassinated) two days before 9-11?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes thats correct. And thanks for the source, it was very useful!